# Python tkinter entry prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to prompt a string of letters one for each time to ask user to click and the game will continue only when user press the correct key.

I am having trouble with the key pressing part. I want to get the text on the button and test if it matches with the prompted letter, if it matches the entry widget will prompt the next letter otherwise it just stays still.

I imported random to shuffle the letters so that every time it will generates different letters. I did not add the `random.shuffle(alist)`, because it does not work.

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random
import tkinter

class KeyboardGame:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title('haha')
        self.value = StringVar()
        self.value.set('click on any key to start...')
        btm_frame = Frame(window, relief=RAISED)
        entry = Entry(window, text=self.value)
        entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=40, pady=5, sticky='EW')
        for i in ['ixnsywfhze', 'uobpqgtav', 'lmjkcdr']:
            frame1 = Frame(btm_frame)
            for j in i:
                button = Button(frame1, text=j, command=self.game)
                button.pack(side=LEFT)
                frame1.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

        btm_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        window.mainloop()



    def game(self):
        n = 0
        alist = ['h', 'c', 'p', 'e', 'm', 'n', 'd']

        self.value.set(alist[n])
        while button['text'] != alist[n]:
            self.value.set(alist[n])
        n += 1



KeyboardGame()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve your problem by [`binding`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) the same event to each button you created.

Hence, in your callback you will need to identify the button which is clicked (which thing your actual code does not do) in order to compare its text using [`cget()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method) method to the content of the entry widget.

Notice that in order to increment `n`  inside `game()` you will need to render it as an [instance variable](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php). You must be careful not to increment it when it reaches the same value as the `alist`'s length.

## Full program

Here are the ideas mentioned above implemented. Note that I focus on fixing your issues only. This means I am not going to comment the best practices you should follow:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter

class KeyboardGame:

   def __init__(self):
       window = Tk()
       window.title('haha')
       self.value = StringVar()
       self.value.set('h')
       self.btm_frame = Frame(window, relief=RAISED)
       self.entry = Entry(window, text=self.value)
       self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=40, pady=5, sticky='EW')
       self.n = 0

       for i in ['ixnsywfhze', 'uobpqgtav', 'lmjkcdr']:
           self.frame1 = Frame(self.btm_frame)
           for j in i:
               button = Button(self.frame1, text=j)
               button.pack(side=LEFT)
               button.bind("<Button-1>", self.game)
               self.frame1.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

       self.btm_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
       window.mainloop()



   def game(self, event):
       alist = ['h', 'c', 'p', 'e', 'm', 'n', 'd']  
       w = event.widget # Identify the button
       if w.cget("text") == self.value.get() and self.n < 6:
           self.n = self.n + 1
           self.value.set(alist[self.n])   

# Start program
if __name__ =="__main__":
   KeyboardGame()
```

## Demo

Here is a screenshot of the running above program:

[image]

Comment: Hi Billal, thanks for solving the problems. I also need to make the keys look square and i tried to set the height and width, but it does not work. Could you help me with it?

Comment: You can create 3 separate frames (as you did) and add the buttons usign `grid()` instead of `pack()`. For each frame, configure its rows (one row per frame) and columns (equal to the number of `j`s in your code) to have the weight equal to 1. Of course, set the `width` and `height` of each button. It must work.